# Dynamically define and set header row to PoiItemReader

Tags: java, apache-poi, spring-batch

I've an excel file: [excel file snapshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh1zb.png)
and going to read the data using PoiItemReader. In case the header row is under 0 index, everything works fine, but if the header row number is 5, the reader cannot process the data. How can we set header row number to reader?
PoiItemReader:

```
@Bean
    public ItemStreamReader<T> reader(final String filePath, final RowMapper<T> rowMapper) {
        PoiItemReader<T> reader = new PoiItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(getResource(filePath));
        reader.setRowMapper(rowMapper);
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);

        return reader;
    }
```

Ideally define dynamically header row, based on input Set.of("column names"...) or just set to reader the header row number